# How do I efficiently redirect TCP packets to server

Tags: vb.net, tcp, proxy, packets

So, I am modifying a game a bit.
It's an online game, and it connects to a server with the port 2050. Now I modified the games code, so it connects to 127.0.0.1 (local) port 2050 instead of the games server. The game wants to send Hello packets and other packets like "Move" packets or Ping packets or Tick packets and the server will then reply with Pong packets or TickReceived etc. I can give you a list of all the packets, but that wouldn't help the question

So when the game sends the packets to my Console application that receives them, well the game cannot start. Why? Because I must reply to it with packets as well. So I need the game to send me the packets, and me to send those packets to the server, receive packets from that server, and sends those packets back to the game, and loop that process so the game can stay alive.

Here is the code I tried using:

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
  Private theListener As TcpListener = Nothing
 Sub Main()
     Try
         theListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2050)
         theListener.Start()
         Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf newclient)

        Console.WriteLine("Listening...")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Sub newclient()
    Try
        Using client As TcpClient = theListener.AcceptTcpClient
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected!")
            Console.ResetColor()
            Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf newclient)
            Using ns As NetworkStream = client.GetStream
                While True

                    Try
                        Dim toreceive(100000) As Byte
                        Dim length As Integer = ns.Read(toreceive, 0, toreceive.Length)
                        Dim text As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(toreceive, 0, length)
                        Console.WriteLine("Received packet.")
                        Try
                            Console.WriteLine("Sending to server.")
                            Dim serverh As TcpClient = New TcpClient
                            Try
                                serverh.Connect("this is the games ip address", 2050)
                                Try
                                    Dim serverstream = serverh.GetStream
                                    serverstream.Write(toreceive, 0, length)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Packet send to the server.")
                                    Try
                                        Dim toreceivefromserver(1000000) As Byte
                                        Dim lengthserver As Integer = serverstream.Read(toreceivefromserver, 0, toreceivefromserver.Length)
                                        Try

                                            ns.Write(toreceivefromserver, 0, length)
                                            Console.WriteLine("Packet that was received from server, sent to client")
                                        Catch ex As Exception

                                        End Try
                                    Catch ex As Exception
                                        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                                    End Try

                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    Console.WriteLine("Problem when trying to send packet to server")
                                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                                End Try
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to server.")
                                MsgBox(ex.ToString)

                            End Try

                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try


                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                        ' Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
                            Console.ResetColor()
                        End Try



                End While

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Console.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

For whatever reason this does not work. I can give you the exceptions, but I would prefer if you had any better ideas to redirect packets or maybe with an easier way.

UPDATE*****

If anyone thinks I dont explain what I need to do here is a picture.
[Top row:What happens - Bottom row: What I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZJaF.jpg)

UPDATE******

Here is the structure of the hello packet. (I know the term "packet" is not correct but please bear with me)

```
    namespace Lib_K_Relay.Networking.Packets.Client
   {
   public class HelloPacket : Packet
    {
     public string BuildVersion;
    public int GameId;
    public string GUID;
     public int Random1;
    public string Password;
    public int Random2;
    public string Secret;
    public int KeyTime;
    public byte[] Key;
    public string Obf1;
    public string Obf2;
    public string Obf3;
    public string Obf4;
    public string Obf5;
    public string Obf6;

    public byte[] RAW;

    public override PacketType Type
    { get { return PacketType.HELLO; } }

    public override void Read(PacketReader r)
    {
        BuildVersion = r.ReadString();
        GameId = r.ReadInt32();
        GUID = r.ReadString();
        Random1 = r.ReadInt32();
        Password = r.ReadString();
        Random2 = r.ReadInt32();
        Secret = r.ReadString();
        KeyTime = r.ReadInt32();
        Key = (byte[])(Array)r.ReadBytes(r.ReadInt16());
        Obf1 = r.ReadUTF32();
        Obf2 = r.ReadString();
        Obf3 = r.ReadString();
        Obf4 = r.ReadString();
        Obf5 = r.ReadString();
        Obf6 = r.ReadString();
    }

    public override void Write(PacketWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(BuildVersion);
        w.Write(GameId);
        w.Write(GUID);
        w.Write(Random1);
        w.Write(Password);
        w.Write(Random2);
        w.Write(Secret);
        w.Write(KeyTime);
        w.Write((short)Key.Length);
        w.Write((byte[])(Array)Key);
        w.WriteUTF32(Obf1);
        w.Write(Obf2);
        w.Write(Obf3);
        w.Write(Obf4);
        w.Write(Obf5);
        w.Write(Obf6);
    }
}
}
```

Now you see packetwriter and packetreader there, which are these:

PacketWriter:

```
namespace Lib_K_Relay.Networking.Packets
{
      public class PacketWriter : BinaryWriter
   {
    public PacketWriter(MemoryStream input)
        : base(input) { }

    public override void Write(short value)
    {
        base.Write(IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(value));
    }

    public override void Write(ushort value)
    {
        base.Write((ushort)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((short)value));
    }

    public override void Write(int value)
    {
        base.Write(IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(value));
    }

    public override void Write(float value)
    {
        byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        Array.Reverse(b);
        base.Write(b);
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        Write((short)data.Length);
        base.Write(data);
    }

    public void WriteUTF32(string value)
    {
        Write(value.Length);
        Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    }

    public static void BlockCopyInt32(byte[] data, int int32)
    {
        byte[] lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(int32));
        data[0] = lengthBytes[0];
        data[1] = lengthBytes[1];
        data[2] = lengthBytes[2];
        data[3] = lengthBytes[3];
    }
}
}

namespace Lib_K_Relay.Networking.Packets
 {
    public class PacketReader : BinaryReader
    {
      public PacketReader(MemoryStream input)
        : base(input, Encoding.UTF8) { }

    public override short ReadInt16()
    {
        return IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(base.ReadInt16());
    }

    public override ushort ReadUInt16()
    {
        return (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((short)base.ReadUInt16());
    }

    public override int ReadInt32()
    {
        return IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(base.ReadInt32());
    }

    public override float ReadSingle()
    {
        byte[] arr = base.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return BitConverter.ToSingle(arr, 0);
    }

    public override string ReadString()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReadBytes(ReadInt16()));
    }

    public string ReadUTF32()
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReadBytes(ReadInt32()));
    }
}
}
;
```

And a class called Packet:

```
 namespace Lib_K_Relay.Networking.Packets
{
  public class Packet
  {
     public bool Send = true;
     public byte Id;

     private byte[] _data;

     public virtual PacketType Type
     { get { return PacketType.UNKNOWN; } }

    public virtual void Read(PacketReader r)
    {
        _data = r.ReadBytes((int)r.BaseStream.Length - 5); // All of the packet data
    }

    public virtual void Write(PacketWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(_data); // All of the packet data
    }

    public static Packet Create(PacketType type)
    {
        Packet packet = (Packet)Activator.CreateInstance(
            Serializer.GetPacketType(type));
        packet.Id = Serializer.GetPacketId(type);
        return packet;
    }

    public static T Create<T>(PacketType type)
    {
        Packet packet = (Packet)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        packet.Id = Serializer.GetPacketId(type);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(packet, typeof(T));
    }

    public T To<T>()
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(this, typeof(T));
    }

    public static Packet Create(byte[] data)
    {
        using (PacketReader r = new PacketReader(new MemoryStream(data)))
        {
            r.ReadInt32(); // Skip over int length
            byte id = r.ReadByte();
            PacketType packetType = Serializer.GetPacketPacketType(id);
            Type type = Serializer.GetPacketType(packetType);
            // Reflect the type to a new instance and read its data from the PacketReader
            Packet packet = (Packet)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            packet.Id = id;
            packet.Read(r);

            return packet;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Use reflection to get the packet's fields and values so we don't have
        // to formulate a ToString method for every packet type.
        FieldInfo[] fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Instance);

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append(Type + "(" + Id + ") Packet Instance");
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
            s.Append("\n\t" + f.Name + " => " + f.GetValue(this));
        return s.ToString();
    }

    public string ToStructure()
    {
        // Use reflection to build a list of the packet's fields.
        FieldInfo[] fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Instance);

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append(Type + " [" + Serializer.GetPacketId(Type) + "] \nPacket Structure:\n{");
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
            s.Append("\n  " + f.Name + " => " + f.FieldType.Name);
        s.Append("\n}");
        return s.ToString();
    }
}

public enum PacketType
{
    UNKNOWN,
    FAILURE,
    CREATESUCCESS,
    CREATE,
    PLAYERSHOOT,
    MOVE,
    PLAYERTEXT,
    TEXT,
    SHOOT2,
    DAMAGE,
    UPDATE,
    UPDATEACK,
    NOTIFICATION,
    NEWTICK,
    INVSWAP,
    USEITEM,
    SHOWEFFECT,
    HELLO,
    GOTO,
    INVDROP,
    INVRESULT,
    RECONNECT,
    PING,
    PONG,
    MAPINFO,
    LOAD,
    PIC,
    SETCONDITION,
    TELEPORT,
    USEPORTAL,
    DEATH,
    BUY,
    BUYRESULT,
    AOE,
    GROUNDDAMAGE,
    PLAYERHIT,
    ENEMYHIT,
    AOEACK,
    SHOOTACK,
    OTHERHIT,
    SQUAREHIT,
    GOTOACK,
    EDITACCOUNTLIST,
    ACCOUNTLIST,
    QUESTOBJID,
    CHOOSENAME,
    NAMERESULT,
    CREATEGUILD,
    CREATEGUILDRESULT,
    GUILDREMOVE,
    GUILDINVITE,
    ALLYSHOOT,
    SHOOT,
    REQUESTTRADE,
    TRADEREQUESTED,
    TRADESTART,
    CHANGETRADE,
    TRADECHANGED,
    ACCEPTTRADE,
    CANCELTRADE,
    TRADEDONE,
    TRADEACCEPTED,
    CLIENTSTAT,
    CHECKCREDITS,
    ESCAPE,
    FILE,
    INVITEDTOGUILD,
    JOINGUILD,
    CHANGEGUILDRANK,
    PLAYSOUND,
    GLOBALNOTIFICATION,
    RESKIN,
    ENTERARENA,
    LEAVEARENA,
    PETCOMMAND,
    PETYARDCOMMAND,
    TINKERQUEST,
    VIEWQUESTS,
    ARENADEATH,
    ARENANEXTWAVE,
    HATCHEGG,
    NEWABILITYUNLOCKED,
    PASSWORDPROMPT,
    EVOLVEPET,
    QUESTFETCHRESPONSE,
    REMOVEPET,
    UPDATEPET,
    UPGRADEPETYARDRESULT,
    VERIFYEMAILDIALOG,
    QUESTREDEEMRESPONSE
}
}
```

This is taken from the source of a proxy called K_Relay, with the difference that the certain proxy allows you to modify the values and send custom packets.

Comment: How does the game handle the data? You are saying "packets" but TCP is a streaming protocol, so there are no packets that you can receive... Do you know if the game deals with message framing? Or even better do you have an example of a complete set of data that the game/server might send?

Comment: The game sends information to the server -> server responds (obviously). I just noticed that the messages are encoded in RC4 before being sent -> then decoded by the server when received and vice versa. So all I want is to "forward" the "packets" or data the game sends, to the server, and vice versa.

An example of a complete set of data that the game might send?I don't quite understand. I could show you an "example" of how the "packet" is structured (the hello packet for example) before being sent, which I will add to the question. If it still doesnt help, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: I just wanted to see the structure of a "packet". I want to determine whether the game performs message framing or not, so please make sure you post every byte in your edit. As I said TCP is a streaming protocol, so the game would likely need some kind of message framing so it knows when a "packet" begins and ends.

Comment: That is a bit much code to read and understand, and it doesn't show very much of what is actually sent. I am more interested in what you receive from the game.